Bookstack app on docker to Windows host DB issue
I have installed a Local DB for bookstack on port 3306 to not loose data after PC reboot on Windows. The goal is to start Bookstack instance from docker container which will connect to external DB on Windows Host.
Two params are set

APP_URL=http://172.25.16.1:6885 #6885 <- Step 1
DB_HOST=172.25.16.1
where IP is taken after reboot each time new: from ipconfig 172.25.16.1

docker-compose.yml
# Source: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/bookstack
version: "2"
services:
  bookstack_bsv2:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/bookstack
    container_name: bookstack_bsv2
    network_mode: "bridge"
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - APP_URL=http://172.25.16.1:6885 #6885 <- Step 1
      #- DB_PORT=3306 #3308 <- Step 1
      #- DB_HOST=bookstack_db_bsv1
      #- DB_USER=bookstack
      #- DB_PASS=yourdbpass
      #- DB_DATABASE=bookstackapp
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_HOST=172.25.16.1
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASS=
      - DB_DATABASE=bookstackapp
    volumes:
      - C:\BookStack\config:/config
    ports:
      - 6885:80
    restart: always
    #depends_on:
    #  - bookstack_db_bsv1
  #bookstack_db_bsv1:
  #  image: lscr.io/linuxserver/mariadb
  #  container_name: bookstack_db_bsv1
  #  environment:
  #    - PUID=1000
  #    - PGID=1000
  #    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yourdbrootpass
  #    - TZ=America/New_York
  #    - MYSQL_DATABASE=bookstackapp
  #    - MYSQL_USER=bookstack
  #    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=yourdbpass
  #  #volumes:
  #  #  - bookstack:/config
  #  ports:
  #    - 3308:3306
  #  restart: always

ipconfig port that works (but this is not something generic, like host.docker.internal)
host.docker.internal does not work.

Is there way to make Bookstack work in a generic way (without binding to IP 172.25.16.1)? Or I have to recreate a container on each time after reboot with new IP in environment variable?


This approach was skipped.

I started to test a Windows-approach with both containers: Bookstack and MariaDB.
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: alter table pages add index pages_template_index(template))emphasized text

# Source: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/bookstack
version: "2"
services:
  bookstack_bsv1:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/bookstack #lscr.io/linuxserver/bookstack:23.02.2 # lscr.io/linuxserver/bookstack <- Step 5
    container_name: bookstack_bsv1
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - APP_URL=http://localhost:6885
      - DB_PORT=3306 #3308 <- Step 1
      - DB_HOST=bookstack_db_bsv1
      - DB_USER=bookstack
      - DB_PASS=yourdbpass
      - DB_DATABASE=bookstackapp
    #volumes:
    #  - C:\BookStack\config:/config
    ports:
      - 6885:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - bookstack_db_bsv1
  bookstack_db_bsv1:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/mariadb
    #image: mysql:8.0.32 # <- Step 3 https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-bookstack/issues/125 error for Windows mount
    container_name: bookstack_db_bsv1
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yourdbrootpass
      - TZ=America/New_York
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bookstackapp
      - MYSQL_USER=bookstack
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=yourdbpass
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config # <- Step 2
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql # <- Step 4 for mysql db folder is different
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    restart: always

But there is a fix for this Windows problem: here linuxserver/docker-bookstack#125 the final post.
With this compose file volumes are created and files are visible. When the containers are dropped and recreated, then docker compose is up once again (folders are left as is) Boostack login starts and data is restored with images on WIndows.
The answer yml:
services:
  bookstack:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/bookstack:23.02.2
    container_name: bookstack
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - APP_URL=http://localhost:6875
      - APP_DEBUG=true
      - STORAGE_TYPE=local
      - DB_HOST=bookstack_db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USER=bookstack
      - DB_PASSWORD=12345678
      - DB_DATABASE=bookstackapp
    volumes:
      - ./bookstackdata:/config
    ports:
      - 6875:80
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - bookstack_db

  bookstack_db:
    #image: mariadb:10.6.12
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    container_name: bookstack_db
    ports:
      - 3308:3306 # 3308 is a DB port visible on HOST
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - TZ=America/New_York
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bookstackapp
      - MYSQL_USER=bookstack
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345678
      - TERM=dumb
    volumes:
      - ./bookstackdbdata:/config
      - ./db-store:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: unless-stopped

Reference: https://github.com/BookStackApp/BookStack/issues/5243
